# Javascript- Good practice for beginners?

Tags: javascript

How should a beginner JavaScript programmer practice knowing they cannot code any program due to limited knowledge.

Is there any place where I can find some exercises to practice as I keep forgetting because I never practice what I learned..

Comment: **https://developer.mozilla.org/en/learn/javascript**

Comment: This question will likely lead to opinionated answers.

Comment: I found `http://www.codecademy.com/` to be a good resource for hands on javascript experience.

Answer (score 1):

There are many place to learn, one that I found very useful was [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) which has set tutorials. I find I learn best when I have an objective that I am working towards, which codecademy provides.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could take a look [here](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/projects) and find a few projects that sound interesting? The only way to get better is to *practice*.